# How can I define a dimension using an external table to define the hierarchy

Tags: ssas, hierarchy

I'd like to define a hierarchical dimension where the hierarchy is defined in an external table as such:
[image: My Dimension Tables]

All the tutorials seem to be geared towards deriving the hierarchy from data in the row.  LeadSourceID/LeadSourceGroupID/LeadSourceViewID are not usable for this as only one is ever populated; they're ETL artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you want there is a **Parent-child Hierarchy** :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174846.aspx

All you need to do is follow the previous article example. There is the part of the subtable you got `LeadSource` which is not explained there, but it's as easy as joining the `LeadSourceHierarchy` table to the `LeadSource` table in your dimension definition (datasource section).

Comment: I specifically don't want a parent-child hierarchy.  There's a distinct many-to-many relationship here.  I realize this will lead to potential double-counting which is perfectly acceptable in this case.